# How can I render vertical, but not horizontal, scroll?

Tags: html, css

I tried incorporating scroll to my overflowing div element in CSS 
using the `overflow` property. But it is attaching both vertical and horizontal scrollbars. I only need vertical scroll. How can I accomplish this with the least lines of code and no javascript or frameworks? Thanks.

```
 .div{
      overflow: scroll;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`overflow-x` for horizontal scroll

`overflow-y` for vertical scroll

So...

```
.div { overflow-y: scroll; }
```

Read more at MDN:

- [`overflow-y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y)
- [`overflow-x`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x)
- [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)